# EF Core how to rollback previous transaction when exception occurs

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core to save order details in multiple tables like `Order`, `OrderItems`, `OrderTransaction`.

I am getting all the details of an `Order` as a single object from the frontend.

If something goes wrong while saving data in subsequent tables. How can I make sure to delete details of that order from previous tables before sending an *order not saved* response to the frontend?

```
string IOrderRepository.AddOrderDetails(AddOrderRequest orderRequest)
{
    // add customer (get customer ID)
    Customer customer = new Customer
            {
                FirstName = orderRequest.customer.FirstName,
                LastName = orderRequest.customer.LastName,
               
            };

    var savedCustomer = customerRepository.AddCustomer(customer);

    // add address (get addressId)
    Address address = new Address
            {
                AddressId = orderRequest.address.AddressId,
                CustomerId = orderRequest.address.CustomerId,
                Address1 = orderRequest.address.Address1,
                ...
            };

    var savedAddress = addressRepository.AddAddress(address);

    // add order (get orderId)
    Order order = new Order
            {
                EmployeeId = orderRequest.order.EmployeeId,
                Description = orderRequest.order.Description,
                OrderTotal = orderRequest.order.OrderTotal,
                EstimatedTax = orderRequest.order.EstimatedTax,
                ...
            };

    var savedOrder = context.Add(order);

    context.SaveChanges();

    // add order items (loop for multiple items)    
    OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem
            {
                ItemId = orderRequest.orderitem.ItemId,
                OrderId = savedOrder.Entity.OrderId,
                OrnamentId = orderRequest.orderitem.OrnamentId,
                ItemAmount = orderRequest.orderitem.ItemAmount,
                ..
            };
    var savedOrderItem = orderItemRepository.AddOrderItem(orderItem);

    // add transaction (loop for multiple payment types)
    OrderTransaction transaction = new OrderTransaction
            {
                TransactionId = orderRequest.orderTransaction.TransactionId,
                OrderId = orderRequest.orderTransaction.OrderId,
                EmployeeId = orderRequest.orderTransaction.EmployeeId,
                AmountPaid = orderRequest.orderTransaction.AmountPaid,
                ...
            };

    return "Success";
}
```

In the above code, I am saving `Order`, `OrderItems`, and `OrderTransactions`. If code fails in `OrderTransaction` - what is the best way to delete data from previous tables?

Comment: Added an answer, hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Transactions will be of use to you. A sample code below

```
using var context = new DatabaseContext();
using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    //your CRUD operations here and SaveChanges();
    //transaction will auto-rollback when disposed if either commands fails
    transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //transaction.Dispose(); - unnecessary
    //how you handle exception
}
```

[Transactions - EF Core explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)

Comment: What if the exception is thrown by middleware like a circular reference error. Such an exception cannot be caught here. How can we rollback or dispose the transaction as necessary?